# Контент не отображается

Tags: php, html, css

У мене появилась проблема. Я сверстал хедер подключил его, но контент который имел бы отображаться после хедера отображается в нем.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
     <title>KinoKings</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Revalia" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>

   <?php require_once "header.php"; ?>

        <div class="container">
          <div class="flex">
            <h1>Фильмы</h1>
          </div>
        </div>

   </body>
   </html>
```

header.php

```
<header>
       <div class="flex">

         <a href="#" class="logo">KinoKings</a>

         <div class="header-menu">
           <span>
             <a href="#">Фильмы</a>
           </span>
           <span>
             <a href="#">Сериалы</a>
           </span>
           <span>
             <a href="#">Аниме</a>
           </span>
           <span>
             <a href="#">Комедии</a>
           </span>
           <span>
             <a href="#">Категории</a>
           </span>
         </div>

         <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Поиск по сайту">

         <a href=""><img src="telegram.svg" alt="" class="telegram"></a>
       </div>
     </header>
```

style.css

```
body {
       padding: 0;
       margin: 0;
       font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
       background: #636363;
     }

     .toggle {
       background: #403C3C;
       width: 100%;
       height: 40px;
       display: none;
     }

     header {
       position: fixed;
       height: 96px;
       background-color: #403C3C;
       width: 100%;
     }

     .flex {
       height: 96px;
       display: flex;
       align-items: center;
       justify-content: space-around;
     }

     .logo {
       font-family: 'Revalia', cursive;
       font-style: normal;
       font-weight: normal;
       font-size: 36px;
       line-height: normal;
       color: #E8BB49;
       text-decoration: none;
     }

     .logo:hover {
       text-decoration: none;
       color: #E8BB49;
     }

     .header-menu a {
       text-decoration: none;
       font-family: Arial;
       font-style: normal;
       font-weight: bold;
       font-size: 20px;
       line-height: normal;
       color: #E8BB49;
       margin-right: 24px;
     }

     .header-menu a:hover {
       text-decoration: none;
       color: #c19a39;
     }

     .search {
       width: 300px;
       height: 50px;
       background-color: #E8BB49;
       outline: none;
       border: none;
       font-size: 20px;
     }

     ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
       text-align: center;
       color: #444444;
       font-family: Arial;
       font-style: normal;
       font-weight: bold;
       font-size: 28px;
       line-height: normal;
     }

     :-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
       align-items: center;
       text-align:center;
       color: #444444;
       font-family: Arial;
       font-style: normal;
       font-weight: bold;
       font-size: 28px;
       line-height: normal;
     }

     ::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
       align-items: center;
       text-align:center;
       color: #444444;font-family: Arial;
       font-style: normal;
       font-weight: bold;
       font-size: 28px;
       line-height: normal;
     }

     :-ms-input-placeholder {
       align-items: center;
       text-align: center;
       color: #444444;
       font-family: Arial;
       font-style: normal;
       font-weight: bold;
       font-size: 28px;
       line-height: normal;
     }

     .telegram {
       width: 85px;
     }

     @media screen and (min-width: 1700px) and (max-width: 1921px) {
       header {
         height: 124px;
       }

       .flex {
         height: 124px;
       }

       .logo {
         font-size: 48px;
       }

       .header-menu a {
         font-size: 36px;
       }

       ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
         font-size: 36px;
       }

       :-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
         font-size: 36px;
       }

       ::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
         font-size: 36px;
       }

       :-ms-input-placeholder {
         font-size: 36px;
       }
     }

     @media screen and (min-width: 1922px) and (max-width: 2561px) {
       header {
         height: 144px;
       }

       .flex {
         height: 144px;
       }

       .logo {
         font-size: 64px;
       }

       .header-menu a {
         font-size: 48px;
       }

       .search {
         width: 400px;
         height: 75px;
       }

       ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
         font-size: 48px;
       }

       :-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
         font-size: 48px;
       }

       ::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
         font-size: 48px;
       }

       :-ms-input-placeholder {
         font-size: 48px;
       }
     }

     @media screen and (min-width: 2562px) and (max-width: 4097px) {
       header {
         height: 169px;
       }

       .flex {
         height: 169px;
       }

       .logo {
         font-size: 84px;
       }

       .header-menu a {
         font-size: 64px;
         margin-right: 48px;
       }

       .search {
         width: 500px;
         height: 120px;
       }

       ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
         font-size: 64px;
       }

       :-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
         font-size: 64px;
       }

       ::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
         font-size: 64px;
       }

       :-ms-input-placeholder {
         font-size: 64px;
       }

       .telegram {
         width: 148px;
       }
     }

     @media screen and (max-width: 1300px) (min-width: 1100px) {
       .header-menu a {
         font-size: 20px;
       }

       .search {
         width: 150px;
       }

       ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
         font-size: 20px;
       }

       :-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
         font-size: 20px;
       }

       ::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
         font-size: 20px;
       }

       :-ms-input-placeholder {
         font-size: 20px;
       }
     }

     @media screen and (max-width: 1099px) and (min-width: 1023px) {
       .logo {
         font-size: 20px;
       }

       .search {
         width: 150px;
       }

       ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
         font-size: 18px;
       }

       :-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
         font-size: 18px;
       }

       ::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
         font-size: 18px;
       }

       :-ms-input-placeholder {
         font-size: 18px;
       }
     }

     @media screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 320px) {

       header {
         height: 240px;
       }

       .flex {
         flex-direction: column;
         height: 240px;
       }

     }

     @media screen and (max-width: 1023px) and (min-width: 769px) {
       .search {
         width: 150px;
         height: 35px;
       }

       ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
         font-size: 18px;
       }

       :-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
         font-size: 18px;
       }

       ::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
         font-size: 18px;
       }

       :-ms-input-placeholder {
         font-size: 18px;
      }

       .header-menu a {
        margin-right: 10px;
        font-size: 14px;
      }

      .logo {
        font-size: 24px;
      }

     }

     .container {
       width: 1115px;
       margin: 0 auto;
     }
```

Comment: `header {  position: fixed;` измените на `header {  position: relative;`

Comment: Спасибо, а есть какой-то другой способ но чтоб position был fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) `header` задаем `top:0;` дабы прижать кверху страницы

2) `.container` даем отступ сверху на высоту хидера `margin:124px auto 0 auto;`